# Using Semaphores in java and storing into array

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am new to using semaphores, so bear with me please. So, lets say I have 7 permits to give out and 49 people(threads) in total are waiting for them. If I acquire() the semaphores for the first 7 people and store them into a list array(store the semaphores of people) for instance by passing them into another class. Then if I go back into that array and loop through and release() the semaphores within that other class, shouldn't that then trigger the other threads waiting to take that next key? Because what I just coded did this and the next 7 threads don't acquire the key. I didn't post the code because I just want to conceptually understand what I am missing out on, and then implement it.

Comment: Usually it's better to post your best attempt at creating a [mcve] (please read the link).

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to have max 7 threads to be active at one time,
you only need 1 semaphore, like this:

```
Semaphore available = new Semaphore(7, true);
```

and let each of your threads call *available.acquire()* (and eventually *available.release()*), against this very semaphore instance (shared by all the threads), and that is it.

Here is what java.util.concurrent.Semaphore javadoc says:

> A counting semaphore. Conceptually, a semaphore maintains a set of
>   permits. Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit is 
>   available, and then takes it. Each release() adds a permit, 
>   potentially releasing a blocking acquirer. 
>   However, no actual permit objects are used; 
>   the Semaphore just keeps a count of the number 
>   available and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're acquiring a semaphore, be sure to release it at some point as well. 
ex Pseudo code:

```
sem = Semaphore.new(2, true)
Thread1 { 
    sem.acquire()
    // Do something
    sem.release()
    }; 
Thread2 { 
    sem.acquire()
    // Do something
    sem.release()
    }
Thread3 { 
    //blocked until one of the first two Thread releases. 
    sem.acquire()
    // Do something
    sem.release()
    }
```

This is adding to zeppelin's point...